# Is there a name for such defined numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, number-systems

I've have defined below new set of like-complex numbers (will be called $\Bbb{HC}$ here as my proposition for name for them is hexagonal-complex):

Let $z = (u,d) \in \mathbb{HC}$ where $u,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $(1,0)(1,0) \triangleq (0,-1)$
- $(0,1)(0,1) \triangleq (-1,0)$
- $(0,1)(1,0) \triangleq (1,0)(0,1) \triangleq (0,1)+(1,0)$
- $\mathbb{HC}$ is a 2d vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

Such defined numbers have following properties, which you can check for yourself:

- $z_1 z_2 = z_2 z_1$
- $z_1(z_2+z_3) = z_1 z_2+z_1 z_3$
- $(1,1)z_1 = z_1$

If we define

- $z^* = (u,d)^* \triangleq (d,u)$
- $|z| \triangleq \sqrt{zz^*}$

Than one can easly proove that:
$|z_1 z_2| = |z_1| |z_2|$

My name hexagonal-complex is from the fact that you can do an identification to complex numbers as:

$(1,0) \leftrightarrow e^{i \pi /3}$

$(0,1) \leftrightarrow  e^{-i \pi /3}$

And the lattice of points $(u,d)$ where $u,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a hexagonal latice in complex plane.

And finally the question is: **do such defined numbers have a name other than what I called them?**

Comment: How can I check for myself the "following properties" when you do not define $(a,b)(c,d)$ in general?

Comment: I wanted to keep it short but what I meant saying it is a 2d vector field is that it can be expressed in a way
 $(a,b)(c,d) = (a(1,0)+b(0,1))(c(1,0)+d(0,1)) = 
ac(1,0)(1,0)+bc(0,1)(1,0)+ad(1,0)(0,1)+bd(0,1)(0,1)$

Comment: You should add the definition of $(a,b)(c,d)$ to the question itself. Keeping it short is one thing, omitting the key definition and thus making the question impossible to answer is another.

Comment: Well then you have specified an isomorphiinms with $\Bbb C$ near the end

Comment: @LeeMosher But the question has already been answered!

Comment: The definition is $(a,b)(c,d) \triangleq (ad+bc-bd,ad+bc-ac)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb{HC}$ does not define a hexagonal lattice in the complex plane; $(1,1)$ is mapped to 1 using your $e^{i\pi/3}$ and $e^{-i\pi/3}$ mappings, which would lie in the centre of one of the hexagons you perceive. Indeed, it's easy to see that a *triangular* lattice is formed instead, and your set of integral points in $\Bbb{HC}$ are the [**Eisenstein integers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).

Since $\Bbb{HC}$ is a 2-dimensional vector space like $\Bbb C$, it is merely $\Bbb C$ with a linear transformation, not anything new.

Comment: Wikipedia says hexagonal lattice and triangular lattice are different names for same thing. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @TomaszKnioła It's a funny thing, since strictly speaking the vertices in a hexagonal tiling are not a lattice. Please accept answer.